# What are the linkers in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, clauses, optional-that

The army has previously rejected Khan’s claims it had anything to do with past purported attempts on his life.

What is the **Linker** in this sentence?

I have noticed many sentences like- **I said it was not fair.** In this case, shouldn't this be like - **I said that it was not fair?**

Comment: It's very common to omit "that" in English when it's used after "said", "claimed", etc.

Comment: Consider the 1970 song by the Partridge Family, *I Think I Love You*, the 1972 Spinners song, *Could It Be I’m Falling in Love*, and Jessica Simpson’s 2000 track, *I Think I'm in Love with You*.